# zIndex issue with pdf inside iframe in IE

Tags: html, css, iframe, z-index

I have a custom HTML handler in my .net project which displays PDF files, In chrome and other browsers it shows properly but in ie the z-index of PDF is above all other stacked elements. I mean when I scroll, the pdf in iframe is coming over my menu and other fixed elements.

Comment: if you have a tried, please share your source code

Comment: i m also facing same issue with almost all browser(safari opera IE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having this same issue with any free floating elements on the page in IE, this function fixes the issue.

```js
function fixPDFzIndexIssue (idToFix) {
    if(!idToFix) return "Please provide the id of the div to fix";

    var $divToFix = $('#' + idToFix);

    $divToFix.wrap("<div class='outer'></div>");

    $(".outer").append("<iframe src='about:blank' class='cover'>");
    $(".cover").css({
        'min-width': '100%',
        'min-height': '100%',       
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'border': 'none',
        'left': 0,
        'top':0,
        'z-index': -1
    });
}
```

It seems that any div that is hovering over a PDF requires an iFrame to be placed underneath it so that it renders over the PDF.

Comment: This is a really clever hack for when you don't control the contents of the iframe!

Comment: Can you share an example calling this function?

Comment: Neat Trick!. I just edited the HTML template and hardcoded the IFrame instead of dynamically appending in javascript. It works for bootstrap modal, dropdown menus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It took me 2 full days to find out a proper fix for this! To make my menu visible at hover over an iframe pdf in IE11. The above solution basically did the trick! However, the above solution didn't work out of the box! In particular, I mean the fact, that the ".cover iframe" is appended to the ".outer" div. What worked for me (and was previously mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044510), was to append the ".cover iframe" to the "inner most" (IOW: deep, nested, lowest level) list elements of the menu ("li.menuelement")!

```
jQuery("li.menuelement").append("<iframe src='about:blank' class='cover'>");
jQuery(".cover").css({
    'min-width': '100%',
    'min-height': '100%',       
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'border': 'none',
    'left': 0,
    'top':0,
    'z-index': -1
});
```

Here now, in my case, I made it work by applying (appending) the ".cover iframe" TO ONLY ONE of my menu's many list elements ("li.menuelement") by above Javascript! And the whole menu becomes visible on hover in front of the iframe pdf! I am so stoked to finally have figured it out!
(BTW: Mine is a real-life fix in a DokuWiki instance running on a server in a corporate environment.)