# Main menu CSS is behind pdf inside iframe in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have created menu bar using CSS3 alongside with iframe tag that load PDF file inside it.

But my CSS menu is hiding behind PDF inside iframe (only in IE). In Google Chrome it works fine. But in IE , not work at all . . The problem is the CSS menu hide behind iframe pdf.

I'm not sure what's wrong with it . I tried to add z-index but it doesn't work.

Here's my code as below.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link href="styletest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper row">
        <nav id="mainav" class="hoc clear"> 
            <ul class="clear">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="drop" href="">About Us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="drop" href="">Sub menu 3</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Extra sub menu 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </nav>
    </div>
    <iframe id="pdf" src="images/test.pdf#zoom=65&scrollbar=0" width= "100%" height= "700"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**teststyle.css**

```
/* Menu Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
nav ul, nav ol {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}
#mainav li a{
    color:inherit; 
    background-color:inherit;
}
#mainav .active a, #mainav a:hover, #mainav li:hover > ab{
    color:#00BCDF; 
    background-color:inherit;
}
#mainav li li a, #mainav .active li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1); 
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
#mainav li li:hover > a, #mainav .active .active > a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-color:#00BCDF;
}
#mainav, #breadcrumb, .sidebar nav {
    line-height:normal;
}
#mainav .drop::after, #mainav li li .drop::after, #breadcrumb li a::after, .sidebar nav a::after {
    position:absolute; 
    font-family:"FontAwesome"; 
    font-size:10px; 
    line-height:10px;
}
#mainav ul {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-top:1px solid #999;   
}
#mainav ul ul {
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:180px;
    text-transform:none;
    font-weight:400;
}
#mainav ul ul ul {
    left:180px; top:0;
}
#mainav li {
    display:inline-block;  
    position:relative;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;  
    padding: 0;
}
#mainav li:last-child {
    margin:0;
}
#mainav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
#mainav li li {
    width:100%;  
}
#mainav li li a {
    border:solid; 
    border-width:0 0 0 0;
}
#mainav .drop {
    padding-left:15px;
}
#mainav li li a, #mainav li li .drop {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 15px;  
}
#mainav ul ul {
    visibility:hidden; opacity:0;  
}
#mainav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility:visible;  
    opacity:1;
}
@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:0px) {
    #mainav ul {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}​
.cover {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
#pdf {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed this problem with Internet Explorer in the past (in my case, an iframe with a Flash element inside it.)

My workaround is to put an empty iframe on the page, behind the element that you actually want to show. This will "cover up" the other iframe, but allow your element to be visible.

In your case, putting the following code inside each LI tag seems to work:

```
<iframe style="background-color: transparent; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; border-width: 0; z-index: -1"></iframe>
```

Of course, those styles should probably just be in a class, and you'd give that class to the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. ill try it first . . :)

Comment: Can you update my code above in your answer ? Because your code seems to work if i add it as empty iframe . but when i add <iframe scr="test.pdf"> it does not work . . menu bar is behind the pdf file